# GSON Class with different body (Error/NoError)

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I want to get the `error` when it's happenning. So, for that I put a variable in my class for `error`. And I have a variable for the "normal body".

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("error")
    public Error ErrorUser;

    @SerializedName("infos")
    public Infos Infos;

    public class Infos {
        @SerializedName("login")
        public String Login;

        @SerializedName("lastname")
        public String LastName;

        @SerializedName("firstname")
        public String FirstName;

        @SerializedName("email")
        public String Email;

        @SerializedName("internal_email")
        public String EmailIntern;

        @SerializedName("location")
        public String Location;

        @SerializedName("netsoul")
        public String Netsoul;

        @SerializedName("studentyear")
        public int SchoolYear;

        public Infos(String login,
                     String lastname,
                     String firstName,
                     String email,
                     String emailIntern,
                     String location,
                     String netsoul,
                     int schoolYear){
            this.Login = login;
            this.LastName = lastname;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.Email = email;
            this.EmailIntern = emailIntern;
            this.Location = location;
            this.Netsoul = netsoul;
            this.SchoolYear = schoolYear;
        }
    }

    public User(Error error){
        Log.d("Here", "Work");
        this.ErrorUser = error;
    }

    public User(Infos infos){
        this.Infos = infos;
    }
}
```

With the normal body (Infos class) that work, but when I try to get error when it's happening I get `user.ErrorUser on reference null object`. So I presume `user` is null, but i don't know why.

**Call**

```
ApiService.getApiService().getInformationUser(SessionManager.getInstance().getToken()).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                User user = response.body();
                if (user.ErrorUser == null)
                    Log.d("Here", user.Infos.FirstName);
                else
                    Log.d("Here", user.ErrorUser.Message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

**Error Class**

```
public class Error {
    @SerializedName("error")
    public String Message;

    @SerializedName("code")
    public int Code;

    public Error(String message, int code){
        this.Message = message;
        this.Code = code;
    }
}
```

If the `message` and the `code` is inversed sometimes, do I need another constructor ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516581/retrofit-handle-json-key-which-has-a-dynamic-structure-array-object

Comment: It's not exactly the same probleme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, with `response.errorBody()`, who contains the error code and the message, in string. I convert it with `GsonConverter()` to my class Error.

```
try {
       Error error = (Error) GsonConverterFactory.create().fromResponseBody(Error.class, Error.class.getAnnotations()).convert(response.errorBody());
       Toast.makeText(this.login.getApplicationContext(), error.errorBody.Message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```